# How to set a boolean true again in Android?

Tags: java, android, boolean, onclicklistener

The `boolean isChecked` is declared first time `true`, than i set in the `OnClickListener` to `false`. What i neeed, is to set `boolean isChecked` again to `true` in the next `OnClickListener`. I know that are not in the same scope but how can i do that?
This is my code:

```
answer[j].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    private boolean isChecked = true;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        RadioButton checkedRadioButton = ((RadioButton) v);
        if (isChecked) {
        if (checkedRadioButton.isChecked()) {
            score++;
            isChecked = false;
        }
        }
    }
});

resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        isChecked = true;
        score = 0;
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to declare your boolean outside of the onclick listeners scope. It will then become more accessbile and you can do whatever you need with it.
Declare it before your onCreate so it has global access in this class.

**Example**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btn, btn2;
boolean isValid;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    isValid = true;

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            isValid = true;
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            isValid = false;
        }
    });

  }
}
```

**EDIT V2**

I took a look at the code you posted again and from what I can tell your logic is saying if isValid is true (you have if(isValid)) then go into your logic. Well to start you are actually declaring the value as false. So in your code say to being isValid = true; What is happening is your logic is saying the boolean isn't true so don't execute the code.

**Edit V3**

Alright I took a look again at all of your code and I can see what is happening. Since the variable is global now it isn't executing a second time once we declare it as false because it never gets a chance to be reassigned to true again. To be honest I don't see the purpose of this variable. It isn't doing anything other than just being there haha. However if you want to have the variable you should just remove the line isChecked = false; As I said I honestly see no purpose for it in your code.

Comment: Please see edit. Mistake on my part. You are going to need to declare it globally before your onCreate

Comment: You can use a mutable boolean wrapper, instead of a `boolean`. Something like this: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/MutableBoolean.htm

Comment: @mithridas sure but is that the easiest and most straightforward way, no. It appears he just has a single boolean that needs to change. Why not just declare globally and manipulate it from there? No need to get more complex than needed.

Comment: hadn't seen the edit, sure this is more straight-forward, +1

Comment: @JordanSeanor: Yes, i need a single boolean to change but if i declare it globally before your onCreate, it makes the `variable score` to stop increasing. It remains  at 1. When it is inside the `OnClickListener` works fine. What can i do?

Comment: @AlexM. Can you post your new code? Just wanna see your declarations.

Comment: @AlexM. Please see the edit. It is just an issue of how your logic is checking the boolean. Just set isChecked  to true instead of false.

Comment: I made the change. Now i have `isChecked = true;` but the `score variable` isn't increasing. Before it worked fine, now it reamins at 1. Do you have any idea why is doing this?

Comment: @AlexM. See latest edit however you may want to rethink this variable entirely.It isn't serving a purpose honestly. There are better ways to do this (though I don't see exactly what you are doing)

Comment: It's very simple what i'm trying to do. I have a 5 radio groups, with 4 radio buttons each. So, each radio button represents an answer to a question. I want when someone checks the correct answer, to increase the `score variable` by one. The `if (isChecked)` is necessary there, because without it, the `score variable` was increasing each time the radio button was checked. I made this, to increase only one time. With `private boolean isChecked = true;` in the scope, the `variable` was increasing fine, now remains at 1. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I figure it out! I moved the `isChecked = true;` inside the `onClick` now works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make It SIMPLE-------

```
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    isValid = true;

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            isValid = true;
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            isValid = false;
        }
```